# JAVA_HOME correct but does not exist

Tags: java

On my Linux machine, this is my ~/.profile

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/src/java/jre1.7.0_79"
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

When I run

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

I get

```
/opt/src/java/jre1.7.0_79
```

as expected. Furthermore, the file exists and is executable, since

```
ls -l $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

yields

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 work work 7718 Apr 10  2015 /opt/src/java/jre1.7.0_79/bin/java
```

However, when I run

```
java -version
```

I get

```
-bash: jre1.7.0_79/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

What is happening here? I'm using Fedora release 14 (Laughlin).

Comment: Is java not working, did you try to run java -version as administrator ?

Comment: I don't have admin rights. If I run ./java from within its directory, it works without problems.

Comment: Which distribution of Linux do you use, did you install java new ?

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the environment variable, do you find something at this location "locate /usr/bin/java" ?

Comment: I'm getting: /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java2html
/usr/bin/javac
/usr/bin/javadoc
/usr/bin/javah
/usr/bin/javaws

Comment: Okay, perhaps the executables of java are in /usr/bin/java ? We could try then to link to it.

Comment: That's not the issue, is it? There's a clear path to the executable specified in $JAVA_HOME, which I can execute directly, and the path in the error message clearly indicates that it is attempting to execute what is in $JAVA_HOME. It just fails for some mysterious reason.

Comment: Yes, it might be so as you say. Perhaps it's something corrupted in the filesystem. However you could try to change the path to test, if it wouldn't work you could rechange it to the old.